# How do I use jest to test a React component that imports a component that imports jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jquery-ui, jestjs, typescript2.0

I am trying to use react-addons-test-utils to shallow render a React component (ComponentA) so that I can snapshot it.

Component A imports Component B.

Component B imports 'jquery' and 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable' and this causes an error when running the tests under Jest:
`jQuery is not defined`

I have tried to use a setupFiles property in package.json to import jquery and jquery UI with only partial success. I get as far as this error: `Cannot read property 'mouse' of undefined`

As I just want a shallow render I don't really care what's in Component B for my test, so I thought I might be able to mock out jquery and jquery UI. However using `jest.mock('jquery)` doesn't fix the `jQuery is not defined` error.

So, are either of the approaches above viable, or do I need to go a different route altogether?

Example code:

**ComponentA.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { AppState } from 'state/appState';
import { ComponentB } from 'components/b';

export class ComponentA extends React.Component<void, AppState> {
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <div>
                <ComponentB/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**ComponentB.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable';

export class ComponentB extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    // Lots of stuff with jQuery UI
}
```

**Test.tsx**

```
// Failed mocking of jquery
jest.mock('jquery');
jest.mock('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable');

// Test file
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactTestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import { ComponentA } from 'components/a';

describe('ComponentA',
    () => {
        const shallowRenderer = ReactTestUtils.createRenderer();

        it('renders correctly',
            () => {
                // Act
                const tree = shallowRenderer.render(
                    <ComponentA/>
                );

                // Assert
                expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
            });
    });
```

**Failed setupFile content**

```
var $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
require('jquery-ui');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to mock out `ComponentB` like this

```
jest.mock('components/b', ()=> ({
  ComponentB: () => 'ComponentB'
}))
```

This will render `ComponentB` as `<ComponentB/>` in your snapshot. Note that the path is relative to your test file.